# How to compare the previous array value withe the next one using for loop

Tags: php, arrays

I want to match the last $data[$i] to next $data[$i] from the array using for loop.
How can i do that..

Below is the code..

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultQuery))
    {
     echo "<br> Hotel Code : " .$row['HotelCode'];
     $info=(str_replace('YES ','',htmlspecialchars_decode($row['PAmenities'])));
     $str_replace='NO ';
     //$info=(str_replace('NO ','',htmlspecialchars_decode($row['PAmenities'])));
     $info_new=array();
     $info_new =(array_unique(explode(";",$info)));
     echo "<br> Hotel Features : " ;
     $string =implode(",",$info_new);
     $string = (str_replace('&apos,',"'",htmlspecialchars_decode($string)));
     //echo $string;

     $data=array();
     $data=(explode(",",$string));
     for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
     {



            echo (str_replace('NO ','',$data[$i])).",";

     }
     echo "<hr>";
```

output:

```
Double bed,Bathroom,Shower,Bathtub,Hairdryer,Terrace,Balcony,Safe,Central heating,Individually adjustable heating,TV,Individually adjustable air conditioning,Direct dial telephone,Small pets allowed under 5 kg,Small pets allowed under 5 kg,Large pets allowed over 5 kg,Large pets allowed over 5 kg,**Wheelchair-accessible,Wheelchair-accessible,**Car park,Car park,Garage,24-hour reception,Wi-fi,Laundry service,Launderette,Lift access,Bar,Restaurant,Highchairs,TV lounge,Year of construction - 1970,Year of most recent renovation - 2005,Number of floors main building - 5,Total number of rooms - 37,Single rooms - 4,Double rooms - 27,Suites - 2,Connecting rooms,Connecting rooms,Hotel,Breakfast buffet,A la carte lunch,Set menu dinner,Nearest Bus / Metro Stop - 5000 m,
```

Comment: What you want to achieve can please be specific. Post your array structures along with expected outputs

Comment: `$rowTable[HotelCode]` is wrong in `$selQuery` because what it means is that you're looking for the row number `HotelCode` in `$rowTable`. Change $rowTable to `$selQuery = "SELECT * FROM dump_hotelamenities WHERE HotelCode='".$rowTable['HotelCode']."' LIMIT 10";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
     {

      if($data[$i] == $lastdata)
      {
          // do stuff.
      }   

            echo (str_replace('NO ','',$data[$i]));
            $lastdata = $data[$i]

     }
```

If you want't to compare the previous value in a loop always store it in a variable at the END of the loop. Check before you set the value in $lastdata and you should be able to check with the previous value every time.

Comment: i tried the code above ..its storing all the previous value in $lastdata..i want to store only the last $data[$i]

Comment: If you only want the last value, try this :
if($i == count($data))
{
    $lastdata = $data[$i];
}